# Get Rack to load config from Gem

Tags: ruby, rack

Is it possible to run Rack and specify that it should look for `config.ru` from one of the project's Gem dependencies rather than the project's files on the local filesystem?

I'm sure this is a 'wrong' pattern, but we've got project A that has a load of front-end static resources. Project B is a Sinatra app that provides the backend services for that web UI to call upon. We separated them into two projects so A could depend on a particular version of B, and be insulated from breaking changes.

B contains the Sinatra app, and the `config.ru` which defines what Sinatra endpoints are mapped to which paths, and additionally that the static resources should be served too.

A has the thinnest sliver of Ruby, essentially just depending on B via a Gemfile.

We want someone to be able to clone project A, do a `bundle install`, and then run `rackup` and have Rack use the `config.ru` inside B's Gem to decide how to configure itself.

Answer (score 0):

The "rackup" command can take options for the include path and a specific library as well as the path to the config file you want to run, so you should be able to pull it off…

```
Usage: rackup [ruby options] [rack options] [rackup config]

Ruby options:
  ...
  -I, --include PATH       specify $LOAD_PATH (may be used more than once)
  -r, --require LIBRARY    require the library, before executing your script
```

If that doesn't work for you, you may need to provide more details on what you are trying to do

Comment: Updated original post - thanks for the prompt reply!